# "Not only… but also" at the beginning of a sentence

Tags: conjunctions, word-order, inversion

Do we always have to use inversion when we start a sentence with "not only… but also"? For example:

Is it correct to write/say:

> Not only they were tall, but also they were strong.

Or

> Not only were they tall, but they were also strong.

Which one is correct?

Comment: The second one is correct.

Answer (score 4):

Only this one is correct:

> Not only were they tall, but they were also strong.

I think, we have to do inversion every single time a sentence or clause begins with *not only*. There is no exception to this rule. I think of this type of structure as a pattern that never breaks and one you simply should commit to memory.

One more example:

> **Not only do** I have to now install the operating system again, **but also** buy a new computer.

It seems to me that we typically do inversion in English when a sentence or clause begins with a negative word or phrase (the operative word here is begins). One of the most common words of that group that immediately springs to mind is *rarely*.

> **Rarely do** you see people using desktop computers nowadays. Most people prefer laptops to them because of their better portability characteristics.

However, there is going to be no inversion when *not only*, or *rarely* for that matter, is found between the subject and the verb:

> I **not only** have to now install the operating system again, **but also** buy a new computer.

Comment: You rarely see people usING desktop computers nowadays. Rarely does not entail inversion necessarily. You see people + verb requires ING. For the NOT ONLY, I agree with you.

Comment: If it's placed at the beginning of a sentence, it does. I thought I made that clear in the post. You should read it again.

Comment: OK, it confused me. Please not the ING though.

Comment: "You see people + verb requires ING" -- where did you learn that rule from? Are you saying "I see a lot of people do that" is incorrect?

Comment: You changed your sentence didn't you? I meant: You rarely see people usING desktop computers nowadays. I guess either can be  used: use or using. It just sounded weird to me. I see a lot of people doing that. I see a lot of people do that. They are not exactly the same...

Answer (score 1):

The inversion does not normally carry over to subsequent independent clauses, so

> *Not only were they tall, but they were also strong*

is the correct version.

Subject-auxiliary inversion occurs in declarative clauses only when certain types of element are put in front position. Negatives are one very obvious type of element that trigger subject-auxiliary inversion when fronted:

*Never had I seen such chaos.*

*At no stage were they in danger.*

"Not only" is clearly negative, but even when used alone, "only" has the same effect:

*Only when I counted the money did I realise the error*.

"Only" is not negative, but it is semantically close to a negative, in that *only John liked it*, for example, entails *No one other than John liked it*.