# "Only if" + comma + inversion

Tags: commas, inversion

Consder the sentence:

> Only if the framework is intuitive(,) can we proceed with formalizing and exploring its variations.

1. Do we need a comma? Can we omit it?
2. Is the inverted word order correct here ('can we' vs. 'we can')?

References to established grammar sources are very welcome.

Answer (score 2):

The inverted order of "can we" is correct in this instance.  I unfortunately cannot say why, except that it sounds very wrong uninverted.

I also believe the comma should be here because this sentence is re-ordered and the comma marks the subordinate clause.  The natural order with the main clause leading would read:

> We can proceed with formalizing and exploring it variations only if the framework is intuitive.

And in this version, the order of "we can" is restored.

Comment: No, a comma is not required here: _Only if the framework is intuitive can we proceed with formalizing and exploring its variations._ Compare: _Only if the framework is intuitive, but not otherwise, can we proceed with formalizing and exploring its variations._ (of course, _but not otherwise_ is a redundancy here). I doubt anybody could provide a hard and fast rule—putting commas in the right places is a murky business.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my short and sweet answer: 1. No need for a comma. Otherwise, you would break the flow of your sentence. 2. The order is fine. This is called inversion. It happens when a clause begins with a negative word ("no", "not", "nowhere" et cetera) or phrases like "only" and "rarely". For details, take a look at this [post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/116249/not-only-but-also-at-the-beginning-of-a-sentence).

Some usage examples:

> **Nowhere** in the regulations **does** it say that I have to pay an additional fee if my calls are over 10 minutes long.
>
> **Rarely do** you hear people say that to other people nowadays.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that a negative construction is only one case when an inversion is used; there are a few others.