# Is it a grammatical requirement to put a "do" between "not only" and main clause?

Tags: grammar

This video is saying (https://youtu.be/yXJYRlxkfu4?t=592)

> not only
>   do I have to end the lesson but also its time to go.

which put a "do" between "not only" and the main clause.

Is it a grammatical requirement to construct a sentence that way?

Comment: Yes, it is. It's called "inversion". See these two links: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/147200/only-if-comma-inversion/147284#147284 and https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/116249 This question has been asked and answered on ELL many times.

Comment: @MichaelRybkin Thanks. In "Not only were they tall, but they were also strong" the "but also" is put apart, the one in my OP is not. Is the one in my OP the right way?

Comment: I think it sounds totally fine.